# TOC depth and issue with bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, pdf, compiling, bookmarks

I am experiencing a trouble when compiling my PDF file. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and Texmaker (PDFLaTeX) to get the file.

I have the following MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb, american]{babel}
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
filecolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
bookmarks=true,
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\section{blabla}

\appendix
\renewcommand\appendixname{Annexes}

\section*{Annexes}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{Annexe~\csname the#1\endcsname~-~}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\section{blabla}
\section{blabla}
\section{blabla}
\section{blabla}
\section{blabla}

\end{document}
```

When compiling the file, the TOC is perfect but the bookmarks in the PDF
are dropped. I know that this issue is coming from that line :

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
```

It seems that this line is dropping all entries for bookmarks because when 
I run this code, the .out file is empty. However, when I drop this line, 
the .out file is all right but subsequent sections after Annexes are shown
both in the TOC and bookmarks

I tried several things but I can't figure out a code that could work.
My objective is to have only the entry Annexes in both the TOC and bookmarks,
without having the subsequent sections (I need those numbered sections in my text).

Does someone is able to help me?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!. With other words: The regular sections should appear, `Annexes` should appear, but not the `blabla` sections?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tocdepth` must be set again to `1`, lately at the end of the document. This can be done either manually or in the `\AtEndDocument` hook. This must be written to the `.toc`.

In addition the `tocdepth` counter must be set to `0` before using the various `blabla` sections.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb, american]{babel}
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
filecolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
bookmarks=true,
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{bookmark}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\section{blabla}

\appendix
\renewcommand\appendixname{Annexes}


\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname}
\section*{Annexes}



\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\makeatletter

\def\@seccntformat#1{Annexe~\csname the#1\endcsname~-~}

\makeatother


\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\section{blabla}
\section{blabla}
\section{blabla}
\section{blabla}
\section{blabla}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's really perfect! Thanks for this quick answer!

Comment: @LucasGuichard: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 0):

Just to include a simpler variation of the solution. A `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` can be included just after the line `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}`.

That is,

```
...    
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % New line
    
\makeatletter
...
```

produces the same result as above, with the bookmarks created in the PDF.